# Does URL encoding guarrantee for all outputted characters to be printable (visible)?

Tags: url, encoding, character-encoding

Does URL encoding guarantee for all encoded characters (after the encoding process) to be printable (visible)? Within its specification and scope? "Printable" here is defined as "visible on paper". Unfortunately could not find any documents mentioning anything similar online

Comment: You mean the characters encoded *by* the URL-encoding, or the characters resulting *from* the encoding?

Comment: the ones resulting *from* the URL encoding

Answer (score 2):

URL encoding uses a very limited set of characters (probably 7-bit ascii), hence is always printable.

All 8-bit codes, plus all of these: ``` !"# $%&' ()*+ ,/:; <=>? @[\] ^``{| }~ ``` are turned into something else.

Perhaps importantly, but confusing:  a single space   is turned into `+`.

The *goal* of the encoding is to avoid parsing problems in URLs:

```
HTTP://example.com/blah.php?my_url=example.com?confusion reighn&x=(a+b)
```

The stuff after `my_url=` should have been encoded.

Comment: I noticed the same, I wonder if the URL standard aims for its result to be always visible on paper

Comment: @tabdiukov - I added to my Answer.